# Add Custom Transaction Body Field in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I added transaction body field to show on invoice.

I can find it on invoice detail page but let me know how could I change the location of that entity field.

I changed SUBTAB to 'Main' and Insert Before in Display tab but this field is showing at the end of main features.

I want to add this fields to Sales Information section.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: I think Insert Before is not working correctly

Comment: I think so. I found another custom transaction body field in that section and I made same changes to my field but I couldn't change location

Comment: If you make changes to any field on the Display tab of a custom field, you need to make sure that you always "Save and Apply to Forms", or click the "Apply to Forms" button; otherwise, your changes will not be reflected in any existing custom forms. If that still doesn't work, you will need to check individual custom forms, as @leibnitz-jacquard indicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all you can configure on its custom record setup. To specify the exact location of the custom field, you must customize each form.

You can do it at Customizations>Forms>Transaction Forms. Then select the form you want to customized and click edit. 

Then once the page has been loaded, go to Screen Fields subtab and there you can change specific properties like Show, Mandatory, Display Type, Field Group, Etc.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how could I know what kinda form I'm using for Invoice? Too many forms there...

Comment: To make it clear. In order to have your layout, you should be creating new form or customize existing one. However, client may have lots of different form depending on their business requirement. So this is something that your functional consultant should identify with them.